# Prevent focus on text input in IE9 - Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have following code but it does noting. Basically I want text input not to be focused.

```
<input id="txt" type="text">


document.getElementById('txt').addEventListener('mousedown', 
    function() {
    this.blur(); // also tried return false;
  }
);
```

I want to attach event dynamically so I used `addEventListener`.

I don't want to use `JQuery` as I am working on bog old javascript file and I don't want to mix two things.

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8y2v3sb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your request, this should work.

```
document.getElementById('txt').addEventListener('mousedown', 
    function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
);
```

Comment: perfecta_______